# Drag a text in d3.js (d3v4)

Tags: d3.js, text, drag-and-drop

I was trying this example in `d3v4` but it but it only works in `v3`: http://jsfiddle.net/HvkgN/4/ 
Anybody know how to make it run in `v4` ?

CSS:

```
#draggable{
    text-anchor: start;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

JS:

```
function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this)
    .attr("y", d3.event.y)
    .attr("x", d3.event.x)
}

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("height", 300)
.attr("width", 300)
.append("text")
.attr("x", 150)
.attr("y", 150)
.attr("id", "draggable")
.text("Drag me bro!")
.call(drag)
```

Comment: Have a look through [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md) `d3.behavior.drag()` is now `d3.drag`

Comment: Thank you, works! Create an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag behaviour in d3 have changed from `d3.behavior.drag()` to `d3.drag()`.

For any further version conversion i'd suggest that you look through [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) first.